# Create a shopping cart rule in Magento based on product attributes

Tags: php, magento

I have products (needles) in a category. Some of them are sold in packs of 100 and some in packs of 500. The quantity of needles in the box is set as a product attribute. I want to apply cart rules based on the total number of needles in the cart. F.x. 10% if you buy 1000-2000 needles, regardless of the combination of 500/100-packs. Don´t think it can be done with the vanilla Magento (CE 1.4.2.0) and haven´t found any module for it. I have tried the Magento forum, but no luck there. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

You could have a single "needles" product and set it's "Qty Increments" to 100. Then if someone wanted, say, 700 needles they just order 700 and the staff would be responsible for picking out a box of 500 and two of 100. That would make the discount possible but wouldn't allow for different SKUs so stock control would be difficult.

Comment: I would rather not use single products, as you mentioned, the stock control will be messed up. Also, the SKUs are imported from the manufacturer. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I found a [fixed prices extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ZetaPrints/extension/5476/zetaprints_fixedprices) that also allows you to set fixed quantities. Perhaps your pack of 100 could have a quantity of 100, and pack of 500 have a quantity of 500, then the total quantity in the cart would be correct. This retains the separate-product setup which allows for SKUs.