# Using one stock for multiple items in Magento

Tags: magento, stock

Ok so what I want is to have multiple simple products draw from the same stock.

**Scenario**

I have a sinle nail file (*Stock:500*)
I have a box of nail files (*50/box*)

I want it so that if someone buys a box then it deducts from the 500 stock of the singles.  Essentially what we do is if someone buys a box, then we ship them 50 of the single files in a box.

Any easy way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a shopping cart rule in Magento based on product attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979257/create-a-shopping-cart-rule-in-magento-based-on-product-attributes)

Comment: Try this extension - https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-associated-or-linked-product-stock-update.html

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a native function of Magento, so there a few approaches you can take to emulate it:

1. Use an external stock management package to keep track of stock and modify Magento to use that. This will require more backend modification.
2. Attempt to fool Magento by using product bundles in clever ways. This will require more frontend modification
3. Develop or find a Bill of Materials plugin for Magento. I didn't see anything after a short search, so you may have to build it. Have that module check the constituent materials for a product before allowing it to be added to the cart.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

1. Create a template for the products that you wish to order this way. This template need only be the files you need to modify, by default it will find the missing files from your default theme;
2. In the template you can place some PHP to write out some extra javascript, of the prototype variety;
3. This frontend code hides the real quantity box, with prototype 'hide' for the relevant css id to make it a hidden form field;
4. The code shows its own quantity box, also an extra field for how many of the fifty packs are required;
5. An onchange event on these boxes gets the values of the boxes, does the required multiplication and addition, then updates the hidden 'real' quantity box with (boxes*50)+singles;
6. On submit the customer sees in the cart the total quantity of the product ordered - this will be total units, not broken down 'per box'. If this is a problem, you can put some words to explain that or modify your main template to handle this and present to the customer the boxes+singles breakdown;
7. Set your products to use the 'new theme' that has your template update code.
8. Test, test, test!

As mentioned by Joseph this cannot be done out of the box. The above workaround is only partial, however, so long as you make it clear to customers that they are buying 500 units instead of 500 boxes then you should have a reasonable solution.

Comment: So basically what I should do is create a custom module then?  What I was thinking was create a module for adding products to the products list but adding another option called cases.  It will ask all the same questions but then allow you to add _ 1 box of product is equal to __#_ of (Simple Product Drop Down) _.  Then when the product is submitted, the box quantity becomes a face value and the box quantity times the # becomes the purchase quantity.

Comment: I don't believe you need to make a module. A theme over-ride will work - with the products that you need to sell this way you specify them to use the 'new' theme (which update the product page product options .phtml file). Alternatively, if you are using attribute sets (and selected attribute sets need to be sold in boxes) then your existing template file can check the attribute set and conditionally show the extra frontend code.